# what does -P flag mean in firebase deploy command?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I saw this -P flag being used in the firebase deploy command 
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase

Visit the url , search "-P"

what I guess from here is that it specifies the folder to deploy , Can you please elaborate !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It specifies the name of the project to deploy to.  It means the same thing as `--project`.  When running `firebase --help`, you can see it in the first few lines of output:

```
Usage: firebase [options] [command]

Options:
  -V, --version                                output the version number
  -P, --project <alias_or_project_id>          the Firebase project to use for this command
  -j, --json                                   output JSON instead of text, also triggers
                                               non-interactive mode
```