# Vue3 + Firebase: Use Different .ENV File For Each Build Type

Tags: firebase, vite, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I've implemented two firebase projects; production (default) and staging

In my Vue3 project.. I have the following env files:

.env.local, .env.production, and .env.staging

`npm run dev //uses .env-local. works fine`

`firebase deploy -P default //uses .env-production. works fine`

HOWEVER.. running:

`firebase deploy -P staging //uses .env-production. !!!WRONG!!!`

My vite.config.js file:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    }
})
```

Example .env file:

```
VITE_ENV = "development"
VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY = "sdasdasdsada"
VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN = "sadadasdasd.firebaseapp.com"
VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID = "sadasdasd"
VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET = "asdasdas"
...
```

QUESTION:

How do I get `firebase deploy -P staging` to use the .env.staging environment?

Comment: why are you using `//uses .env-production` when you want to deploy to staging? Shouldn't it be `//uses .env-staging` ? Or did I miss understood something ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think `//uses .env-production` is just a comment to say that it what the command uses and it not what OP wants.

Comment: Are you using Firebase Hosting or are your projects Cloud Functions? Either way, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442739) with answers covers just about everything.

Comment: What exactly are you deploying (static hosting, cloud functions)?  How exactly are you using the variables in the dotenv config files? The only thing that `-P` does with the Firebase CLI is [select the name of the Firebase project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60697727/what-does-p-flag-mean-in-firebase-deploy-command) used for deployment.  It doesn't say anything about dotenv files.

Comment: @DougStevenson static hosting. I'll update question with example env.. fairly basic

Comment: How are you trying to use these variables? You're showing config but not how you expect the config to affect anything. Vite runs  but not at all in Firebase - it is a local development environment tool. Firebase Hosting just serves static content.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adding a new script for staging deployment in your `package.json`: that script will set the appropriate [environment variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) before deploying to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).

```json
"scripts": {
    "deploy:staging": "cross-env VITE_ENV=staging vite build && firebase deploy -P staging"
}
```

[`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) (`npm install --save-dev cross-env`) is used to set environment variables in a platform-independent way. It is in maintenance mode as a project, but still works well.

Your `package.json` should now include the new deployment script:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "deploy:staging": "cross-env VITE_ENV=staging vite build && firebase deploy -P staging"
    // other scripts
  }
  // rest of your package.json
}
```

---

The provided [`vite.config.js`](https://vitejs.dev/config/) does not currently handle custom environment variables. You would need to modify it to make sure it loads the correct environment variables based on the `VITE_ENV` value.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    const env = require(`./.env.${mode}.js`).default;
    return {
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
        },
    },
    // Add other necessary configurations
    define: {
        'process.env': env
    }
    };
});
```

That would load the appropriate `.env` file based on the `mode` (which is set by `cross-env VITE_ENV=staging` or other environment settings).

---

The example `.env` file you mention suggests that these are standard dotenv files.
However, to be imported in `vite.config.js`, they need to be in JavaScript object format. Ypu might consider converting the `.env` files into JavaScript modules. For instance, consider using [`abdennour/dotenv-to-js-object`](https://hub.docker.com/r/abdennour/dotenv-to-js-object) ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/abdennour/dockerfiles/blob/25283b0b1d269d5e6a5a9577a8da1fe81d1b08e6/docker-images/dotenv-to-js-object/Dockerfile), using this [bash script `fry`](https://github.com/abdennour/dockerfiles/blob/25283b0b1d269d5e6a5a9577a8da1fe81d1b08e6/docker-images/dotenv-to-js-object/fry)) to convert the `.env` files into JavaScript modules, which would look like.

```js
export default {
    VITE_ENV: "staging",
    VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY: "your_staging_firebase_api_key",
    VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: "your_staging_firebase_auth_domain",
    // other staging variables
};
```

Repeat this for each environment (`.env.production.js`, `.env.local.js`, etc.).

That could be part of your npm script, to include this conversion step. For instance:

```json
"scripts": {
    "convert-env": "docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app abdennour/dotenv-to-js-object /app/.env.staging",
    "deploy:staging": "npm run convert-env && vite build && firebase deploy -P staging"
}
```

But you could use the [`fry` script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abdennour/dockerfiles/25283b0b1d269d5e6a5a9577a8da1fe81d1b08e6/docker-images/dotenv-to-js-object/fry) directly, without Docker:

```json
"scripts": {
  "convert-env": "./fry.sh --src=./.env.staging --env-vars --dest=./ --dest-filename=.env.staging.js", 
  "deploy:staging": "npm run convert-env && vite build && firebase deploy -P staging"
}
```

That assumes your `.env.staging` file is in the root directory of your project. The `convert-env` script will create a `.env.staging.js` file, which can then be imported into your `vite.config.js`.
That would automate the process of converting `.env` files.

---

Now, when you want to deploy to your staging environment, you would use the new `npm` script:

```bash
npm run deploy:staging
```

That should make sure the correct environment variables are used for each deployment type.

```
[ Vue3 App ] -- .env.staging -------------------- [ Vite Build ]
   |                                                    |
   |----------- .env.production -- [ Vite Build ]       |
                                                   (build artifacts)
                                                        |
                                                  [ Firebase Deploy ]
                                                        |-P staging
                                                        |-P default
```

Make sure the `.env` files are correctly named (`.env.local`, `.env.production`, `.env.staging`) and contain the respective environment-specific variables.

Comment: Beauty.. going to try this. One thing tho.. my Vite.config likely needs to be set-up similar to the example here.. how would I translate what you suggest to this? Complete newb with vite https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config

Comment: updated my question to include my current vite.config.js file for reference.

Comment: @MikeBarwick I have amended my answer to address the `vite.config.js` and `.env` files, based on your edit.

Comment: is there a way without docker? I'm on Mac and it's super annoying running deamon

Comment: @MikeBarwick Sure, I have amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: trying to run fry.. from root project.. permission denied tho.. "convert-env": "./fry.sh .env.staging > .env.staging.js"

Comment: "convert-env": "fry.sh .env.staging > .env.staging.js" -> "sh: fry.sh: command not found"

Comment: @MikeBarwick Yes, it needs to be in your $PATH, or you would need to use a relative path, like `./fry` instread of `fry`. This assumes you have created the script file named `fry`, and make it executable (`chmod 755 fry`).

Comment: first, thanks for taking time on this.. second.. got script to run, but errors out: ./fry: line 176: exec: .env.staging: not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255955/discussion-between-mike-barwick-and-vonc).